# Order in column a N number of number rows on a txt file with java

Tags: java, string, file, exception, txt

I was trying to make an assignment my teacher gave and I have to order in column a set of number rows in a text file with Java
Disclaimer: my teacher doesn't want the Scanner class for this assigment: the sample data is this:

```
17,10,
6, 90,
11
```

The result should be this:

```
17
10
6
90
11
```

My code is this:

```
package esercizio.prova.verifica;
import java.io.*;
public class EsercizioProvaVerifica {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //read the file and put content in a String array
    String[] str={};
    String line = "";
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\sorgente\\file.txt"));
        int i=0;
    
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null || i<str.length){
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line + i);
            str[i]=line;
            i++;
       }
    
       reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e){}
    
    
    // Write array on file
    for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
    try{
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\sorgente\\file.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
             bw.write(str[i] + "\n"+ "");
        }
        bw.close();
     }catch (IOException e1){}}}
```

The problem is everytime I run the program, the text in the file disappears and Java returns the following output:

```
run:
6, 90,0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at esercizio.prova.verifica.EsercizioProvaVerifica.main(EsercizioProvaVerifica.java:16)
C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2rc\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I searched for hours and I can't find the problem, Can someone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you want people to read it (I've submitted an edit this time, but most people won't). NetBeans should highlight a line in red when it fails, can you add a comment on that line (`// …`)? The error message mentions line 16, but it's hard to read in a web post, and I don't know if you removed anything when sending the file.

Comment: A part of the problem: you are calling `readLine` twice, once the while's condition, and a second time inside the while's block. This means that you are reading two lines every loop, so you are throwing away every other line. But that's not the reason why it's crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.

- You try to write to an array with no allocation.
- You read within the while directive as well as within the while block.  This causes you to skip values.
- You're not splitting the values on their delimiter (`,`)
- You're ignoring exceptions.

Here is one way to do it.  There are quite a few.  This uses a single loop to do both reading and wrting.

- Open up the source file and create a temporary output file.
- As you read in the line
- split on the remaining `,s` and write out the values.
- when finished, close each file and then delete the original and then rename to the original.

```
try {
    File input = new File("C:\\sorgente\\file.txt");
    File output = File.createTempFile("temp",".txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
    
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for(String s : line.split(",")) {
            writer.append(s.trim());
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    input.delete();
    output.renameTo(input);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize an empty array of length zero. The array length must be determined beforehand and cannot be changed during runtime. But since you don't know how many lines your file can have, arrays are not the right data structure. use a list instead.

Use try with resource. so you don't have to close your reader and writer manually.

While writing back you do not split the single numbers. Split each line at the commas.

Use the system line separator instead of \n so that your code behaves the same on all operating systems.

Don’t ignore exceptions, i.e don't do `catch(IOException e){}`

Example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\sorgente\\file.txt"))){
            // read line by line and add to list
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }

        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\sorgente\\file.txt"))){
            for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
                //splite each line at the commas
                String[] parts = lines.get(i).split(",");
                for(int k = 0; k < parts.length; k++){
                    //remove unnecessary spaces befor ore after comma using trim method
                    bw.write(parts[k].trim());
                    bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
    }
}
```